# docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket

Tags: permissions, sudo, docker, gradle

on the Ubuntu 18.04 system I have cloned a project and to run it needs `gradle` but at running the gradle command `gradle swiplRun` I get the following error

> > Task :dockerRun FAILED
> >     docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/containers/create?name=swiprolog: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
> >     See 'docker run --help'.
>
> Task :dockerRunStatus FAILED
>   Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/containers/swiprolog/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

to solve I tried

```
$ sudo groupadd docker
$ sudo usermod -a -G docker myname  
"and once with"
$ sudo gpasswd -a myname docker
```

so I can run docker commands without sudo, but the same error
also `./gradlew --stop` and logout/login and reboot did not work too.

is it because of Docker or Gradle?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error

> Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/json?all=1": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

when running docker ps

What helped was:

```bash
sudo gpasswd -a $USER docker
newgrp docker
```

See Stack Overflow [Docker-compose up : Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(61, 'Connection refused'))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64662372/docker-compose-up-error-while-fetching-server-api-version-connection-aborte)

Another way:

```bash
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
sg docker -c "bash"
```

It does the same as above, no need to run both two-liners.

If you checked all of these commands once, and you still get the error, you know that it is not a Docker, but a Gradle problem. It would mean  that Gradle does not get the needed sudo rights at one point. That could happen from a local and not system-wide python installation on the container, just to name one example.